# Convert a WKT string within a text file to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr or GDAL command line tools

Tags: gdal, geojson, convert, ogr2ogr, well-known-text

I have a `testwkt.txt`. Printing it's contents in terminal:

```
% cat testwkt.txt 
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))
```

I would like to convert the WKT string to GeoJSON. I expect the output to be a file with contents something like:

```
{
'type': 'FeatureCollection',
'features': [{'id': '0',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0]]]}}
]
}
```

I can do the task using Python. How can I do it using `ogr2ogr` or GDAL command line tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read some documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html. Edit the text file and add a header line and enclose the WKT between double quotation marks. Notice ending comma in the header. It is only needed with a single column CSV.

```
wkt,
"POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))"
```

Make a check with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo CSV:testwkt.txt -al -so
INFO: Open of `CSV:testwkt.txt'
      using driver `CSV' successful.

Layer name: testwkt
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (0.000000, 0.000000) - (1.000000, 1.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
wkt: String (0.0)
```

Looks good, convert.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON testwkt.json CSV:testwkt.txt
```

The result is

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "testwkt",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "wkt": "POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 1.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

If you do not want to keep the WKT as a string, follow the documentation

> KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=YES/NO (default YES) Expose the detected X,Y,Z or
> geometry columns as regular attribute fields.

Usage: Add `-oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO` into ogr2ogr command.

Comment: Great, this works. I added another answer clarifying how to get the csv without having to manually edit the txt. (I have many of these files, and I aim to do the whole process programatically.) Feel free to copy it into this answer. If it's copied, I delete my own answer, so we can have one single answer for the whole problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/441877/191643) works, the bit missing is how to edit the initial file programatically. We can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "wkt," > testwkt.csv
echo -n '"' >> testwkt.csv
cat testwkt.txt | tr -d '\n' >> testwkt.csv
echo '"' >> testwkt.csv
```

From here, one can go to `ogrinfo` & `ogr2ogr` step as suggested in the accepted answer (use `testwkt.csv`).